# Fill in the table automatically with numbers with a certain step

Tags: tables, loops

[image]

Let me give you an example of how I started to solve this problem (but without success):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \caption{Example table with different initial numbers and equal step}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            A & B & C & D \\
            \hline
            \newcounter{currentA}
            \newcounter{currentB}
            \newcounter{currentC}
            \newcounter{currentD}
            
            \setcounter{currentA}{1}
            \setcounter{currentB}{10}
            \setcounter{currentC}{100}
            \setcounter{currentD}{1000}
            
            \whiledo{\value{currentA} < 21}{
                \thecurrentA &
                \thecurrentB &
                \thecurrentC &
                \thecurrentD \\
                \hline
                \stepcounter{currentA}
                \stepcounter{currentB}
                \stepcounter{currentC}
                \stepcounter{currentD}
            }
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you be interested in a LuaLaTeX-based solution? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I define a `\makerows` command taking three arguments: the first argument is the number of rows; the second one is the list of starting points; the final argument is the list of steps.

The row building function is repeated as many times as specified. At each step, the current sequence of values is stored in the appropriate way; then the new one is computed by adding the steps.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makerows}{mmm}
 {% #1 = number of rows, #2 = list of initial points, #3 = list of steps
  \tl_clear:N \l__anton_rows_tl
  % store the steps
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__anton_row_steps_seq { #3 }
  % initialize
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__anton_row_current_seq { #2 }
  % build the rows
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \__anton_row: }
  % deliver them
  \tl_use:N \l__anton_rows_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \l__anton_rows_tl
\seq_new:N \l__anton_row_previous_seq
\seq_new:N \l__anton_row_current_seq
\seq_new:N \l__anton_row_steps_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__anton_row:
 {
  % build the current row
  \tl_put_right:Ne \l__anton_rows_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l__anton_row_current_seq { & } }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__anton_rows_tl { \\ }
  % compute the next one
  \seq_set_eq:NN \l__anton_row_previous_seq \l__anton_row_current_seq
  \seq_clear:N \l__anton_row_current_seq
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l__anton_row_steps_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Ne \l__anton_row_current_seq
     {
      \fp_eval:n { ##2 + \seq_item:Nn \l__anton_row_previous_seq { ##1 } }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{A} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{B} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{C} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{D} \\
\hline
\makerows{10}{1,0.1,0.2,10}{1,0.01,0.2,2}
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Example table with different initial numbers and different steps}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Edited to respond to followup in comments.]

It's basically an expansion problem. This probably doesn't tell you much; as far as I can figure out, pretty much everything is an expansion problem.

You want `tabular` to see the contents of the cells along with the `&` and `\\` . So you need to assemble the contents first, expanding and incrementing the counters, and only then let `tabular` see the result all-at-once.

The easiest way to control expansion these days is to use `expl3`. Because this syntax is not really intended for use in documents as such, we define a command `\ahtoh[<key-value list>]` which takes an optional `<key-value list>`. This allows you to vary the starting values, number of loops and size of steps.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702971/ i gwestiwn ahtoh: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702968/
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_ahtoh_fordos_tl
\keys_define:nn { ahtoh }
{
  a .int_set:N = \l_ahtoh_currenta_int,
  b .int_set:N = \l_ahtoh_currentb_int,
  c .int_set:N = \l_ahtoh_currentc_int,
  d .int_set:N = \l_ahtoh_currentd_int,
  loops .int_set:N = \l_ahtoh_loops_int,
  step .int_set:N = \l_ahtoh_step_int,
  a .initial:n = 1,
  b .initial:n = 10,
  c .initial:n = 100,
  d .initial:n = 1000,
  loops .initial:n = 20,
  step .initial:n = 1,  
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_add:Nn { NV }
\NewDocumentCommand \ahtohnos { O{} }
{
  \keys_set:nn { ahtoh } { #1 }
  \tl_clear:N \l_ahtoh_fordos_tl
  \int_step_inline:nn { \l_ahtoh_loops_int }
  {%
    \tl_put_right:Ne \l_ahtoh_fordos_tl {
      \int_to_arabic:n { \l_ahtoh_currenta_int } \noexpand&
      \int_to_arabic:n { \l_ahtoh_currentb_int } \noexpand&
      \int_to_arabic:n { \l_ahtoh_currentc_int } \noexpand&
      \int_to_arabic:n { \l_ahtoh_currentd_int } \noexpand\\
      \noexpand\hline 
    }
    \int_add:NV \l_ahtoh_currenta_int \l_ahtoh_step_int
    \int_add:NV \l_ahtoh_currentb_int \l_ahtoh_step_int
    \int_add:NV \l_ahtoh_currentc_int \l_ahtoh_step_int
    \int_add:NV \l_ahtoh_currentd_int \l_ahtoh_step_int
  }
  \l_ahtoh_fordos_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Example  table with different initial numbers and equal step}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    A & B & C & D \\
    \hline
    \ahtohnos
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    A & B & C & D \\
    \hline
    \ahtohnos[a=-10,b=-100,c=100,d=10,loops=20,step=-5]
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: tables of stepped integers]

If you only want a single table, you could dispense with the variables altogether and simply calculate `0+<loop number>`, `9+<loop number>` etc. But I'm assuming your real use-case is a bit more complex than the example in your question.

Comment: I can't run your code in MiKTex, TeXworks

Comment: @Антон - When did you last update your MikTeX distribution?

Comment: +1 for "[in TeX,] pretty much everything is an expansion problem". :-)

Comment: I had the July version. Now I have installed a new version and everything is working! Thanks!!!

Comment: Is it possible to make a step that is not equal to one? And the fractional step? For example 0.01 ?

Comment: @Антон Please see edit above. Varying the step is straightforward provided it is an integer. For a fractional step, you'd need a different approach. In your question, you used counters, which are always integers. You can't `\stepcounter` with a fractional value, for example. `_int` is the `expl3` version of a counter and only deals with integers. So `456` or `-13` are fine, but `0.1` won't work. I'd suggest asking a new question if you need that and linking to this one for context. Tell us what level of accuracy you need, whether speed matters and whether LuaTeX is an option.

Comment: @Антон Traditionally, TeX does fractional arithmetic using dimensions, but the results are not accurate. If you step and step again, the inaccuracies accumulate. For some purposes, that may be OK; for others, it may not be. For greater accuracy, you can use floating point, but the greater precision has some cost in terms of efficiency. If you need a lot of calculations, that may slow compilation significantly; if only a few, the difference will be negligible. So for fractional, you need to think a bit about what you need as there are more factors involved than for integers.

Comment: As a result, I have to fill in the table shown in the photo. This is just a piece of the table, in fact there are 40  rows

Comment: @Антон Like I say, you can do it, but not with the counter-based approach you were working on. See egreg's answer for one way to accommodate fractional steps.

Answer (score 4):

The same table as shown in egreg's answer can be created with OpTeX by following code:

```
\def\B{0.1} \def\C{0.2} \def\D{10}
\table{|c|c|c|c|}{\crl
  A & B & C & D \crl
\fornum 1..10 \do{
   #1 & \B & \C & \D 
   \xdef\B{\expr[2]{\B+.01}}% 
   \xdef\C{\expr[1]{\C+.2}}%
   \xdef\D{\expr[0]{\D+2}} \cr}
\crl}

\bye
```

Comment: No, it's not the same. You don't get automatically the number of columns.

Comment: It is the same. I referenced the picture of the output, no the code.